# determinant of a matrix with rank p

Tags: linear-algebra

I was going through the book 'Lectures in Abstract Algebra - Vol 2' by Jacobson, and one of the proofs involved the following fact:

If A is an r by n matrix with determinantal rank p, we can re-arrange the matrix so that the determinant of the submatrix obtained by taking the 1st p rows and columns is non-zero. We can call this submatrix B.

Now denote the submatrix consisting of the 1st p+1 rows and columns by D. Let $B_i$ = cofactor of $A_{i,p+1}$ in D.

By definition, $B_{p+1}$ = B.

This is the part that I didnt get:

$B_1.A_{1,j} + B_2.A_{2,j} + ... + B_{p+1}.A_{p+1,j}$ = 0 , for j = 1,2,...,n.

Is this some formula for calculating determinant? I looked up some formulae and I didn't find any that matches this. I don't understand why this sum is 0 for any j other than j = p+1.

edit:

I manually tried the 2x2 (with rank = 1) and 3x3 (with rank = 2 and 1) cases. in case of j >= p+1, the sum equals the determinant of a p+1 x p+1 submatrix, which should be 0 by definition of determinantal rank. In case of j < p+1, the terms seem to cancel each other but I cant spot a pattern or reason why. I tried using induction as well but couldn't make progess.

Comment: Laplace's expansion theorem for determinants.

Comment: But which row/column do we expand on? suppose j = 1. Since B_i = cofactor of A_i,p+1, we have to take the (p+1)th column right? so then how are we taking A_1,1 or A_2,1, as coefficients? Thats why I dont understand why the statement is true for j not equal to p+1